# Separate database settings based on logged in Django 1.8 user

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, postgresql-9.4

I want a role at Postgresql 9.4 level (thus I would not use the Django permission system) to be the data owner and other for read access.

In other words:
PG Role data_owner (content manager)  --> Django group Publishers (RW)
PG Role data_user   (content reader)  --> Django group Subscribers (R)

The data owner role (through the Publishers group) would be the responsible for feeding the app with data whilst other users are just retrievers with read only access.

Some tables like the activity stream need to be read write for all users.

Then the approach would be:

- content tables: role data_owner rw, others r
- functional tables: all rw

Optional:

- configuration tables: role system_owner rw, ohters r

Where r means select permission and w means insert, update and delete permissions.

How can this be better achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest way is defining two databases in settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'my_db',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'USER': 'data_owner', 
        'PASSWORD': 's3krit'
    },
    'users': {
        'NAME': 'my_db',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'USER': 'data_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'priv4te'
    }
}
```

And then, in the views, access the models with the **using()** function, like this:

```
# This will run on the 'default' database.
objects.all()

# So will this.
objects.using('default').all()

# This will run on the 'users' database.
objects.using('users').all()
```

Also, you can select a database for save like this:

```
my_object.save(using='_users')
```

Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/multi-db/

Any other suggestion?